# How to set "Start without debugging" in VS in topbar

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

How can I set "Start without debugging " in the top-bar of the Visual Studio 2019 IDE, instead of "Local Windows Debugger". I find it annoying that every single time I need to press CTRL + F5 to start without debugging.

I looked through settings but I didn't see anything. Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add virtually *any* command to the VS-2019 IDE's toolbars. At the right-hand side of the tooolbar where you want your command to go, click the small down-arrow and select the "Add or Remove Buttons" command from the pop-up:

[image]

Then, if the command you want is *not* shown in the list of 'available' buttons, select the "Customize" command (near the bottom). Then, in the pop-up box, click the "Add Command" button:

[image]

In the next pop-up, for the "Start Without Debugging" command, you have to (odd though it may seem) select the "Debug" category from the left-hand list and scroll down (some way) in the right-hand list to find it:

[image]

Once selected, click "OK" ad "Close" the first pop-up. The command button will now appear (probably at the extreme left-hand side) on the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the toolbar, pick Customize from the drop down menu

Click the Commands tab in the dialog that appears

Click the Toolbar radio button

Pick the 'Standard' option from the drop down menu to the right of the Toolbar button

Click the Add Command button

Click the Debug category on the left

Scroll down to list on the right to find the 'Start without Debugging' command and select it.

Click OK

etc. etc.